# change the nodes of a linked list

Tags: c, list, function, nodes, swap

The code for my list nodes is:

```
struct list{                                        
    int value;                                      
    struct list *next;                               
};
```

i want to make a swap function like this:

```
void swap(struct list *head , int v)
```

User gives a number v and the program search it in the list and changes it with the next node.
For example if user gives 3 and list contains :2 -1 7 3 -5 4 the swap function will make the list like this :2 -1 7 -5 3 4
Any ideas ?

I made the following code for swap :

```
void swap(struct list *head, int v){
       struct list *before=NULL;
       struct list *found=NULL;
       struct list *after=NULL;


if(head==NULL){
   printf("Case of empty list !\n);
}

before=head;
found=head;
while(found->next !=NULL){
       if (found->value==v){
                after = before->next;
                before = found->next;
        }
        before = found;
        found = found->next;
        after = found->next;
}
return;
}
```

Comment: What have you written till now which did not work in your swap function?

Comment: i have used in the function 3 pointers initialized with head , then made a while to find the node with the value required . The first pointer was at node before the node with the value , the other after and the third at the node with the value .

Comment: Please add it to your original question, using Edit button.

Comment: @reshad yeah I am sorry , i fixed it...

Comment: @Katerina Tsellou Do you indeed want to swap the nodes or only swap the values stored in the nodes?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow   the nodes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way :

1. Search for the `int v` in linked list till the last node
2. If it found and if that node is not a last node then swap the data of the node.
3. If it is a last node then you can't swap. You have to find another case
4. If that node is a only node then also you have to consider another condition just like if it will be last node

If you want to swap node then try this code

```
void swap(node *head, int v) {

node * prev,*curr,*NEXT,*temp

curr=head;

prev=curr;

NEXT=curr->next;

while(curr!=NULL){

if(curr->data==v){

  if(curr->next!=NULL){
   prev->next=NEXT;
   temp=NEXT->next;
   NEXT->next=curr;
   curr->next=temp;

   break; 
   }

  else{
     printf("\nThere is no further node to swap ");
    }
 } 

 prev = curr;
 curr = curr->next;
 NEXT = curr->next;

} 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you only have the numbers in the structure, you should just be able to swap them.

Be careful for the following exceptions:

- When there is no element to swap (i.e. end of the list).
- When the element doesn't exist in the list.

In your code:

```
void swap(struct list *head, int v){

     int temporary_number;
     struct list *found=NULL;

     if(head==NULL){
        printf("%s", "Case of empty list !\n");
     }

     found = head;

     while(found->next != NULL){
       if (found->value == v){
                temporary_value = found->next->value
                found->next->value = found->value
                found->value = temporary_value
        }
        found = found->next
     }

     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well working off your example, you can do something like the following:
Find the node containing 3 in the list. This should be easy since you're passing in the pointer to head of the list. Once you find 3, save -5 in a temporary node pointer. Have the node with "7" point to the same location as the temporary pointer. Then have -5's next pointer point to 3. Lastly, reassign 3 to point to 4. The logic is the same as any swap function. You will use a temporary variable to store what you are swapping. Then reassign values.

More general explanation:

1. Traverse to node containing v.
2. Then, save the next node in a temporary pointer
3. Set the previous node's next pointer equal to the temporary pointer
4. Set the next pointer of the node containing "v" equal to the temporary node's next pointer
5. set the temporary pointer's "next" pointer equal to the node containing "v"
6. Consider edge cases such as: node can't be swapped cause it is the last node in the list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be hurry. :)
As you said that you need to swap the nodes themselves instead of swapping just their values then here you are. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{                                        
    int value;                                      
    struct list *next;                               
};

void push_front( struct list **head, int value )
{
    struct list *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );

    if ( tmp )
    {
        tmp->value = value;
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }
}

void display( struct list *head )
{
    for ( struct list *tmp = head; tmp; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", tmp->value );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}    

void swap( struct list **head, int value )
{
    while ( *head && ( *head )->value != value )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    if ( *head && ( *head )->next )
    {
        struct list *next = ( *head )->next->next;
        ( *head )->next->next = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        ( *head )->next->next = next;
    }        
}

int main( void ) 
{
    struct list *head = NULL;

    push_front( &head, 4 );
    push_front( &head, -5 );
    push_front( &head, 3 );
    push_front( &head, 7 );
    push_front( &head, -1 );
    push_front( &head, 2 );

    display( head );

    swap( &head, 2 );
    display( head );

    swap( &head, 2 );
    display( head );

    swap( &head, 2 );
    display( head );

    swap( &head, 2 );
    display( head );

    swap( &head, 2 );
    display( head );

    swap( &head, 2 );
    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 -1 7 3 -5 4 
-1 2 7 3 -5 4 
-1 7 2 3 -5 4 
-1 7 3 2 -5 4 
-1 7 3 -5 2 4 
-1 7 3 -5 4 2 
-1 7 3 -5 4 2
```

Or a more interesting example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{                                        
    int value;                                      
    struct list *next;                               
};

void push_front( struct list **head, int value )
{
    struct list *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );

    if ( tmp )
    {
        tmp->value = value;
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
    }
}

void display( struct list *head )
{
    for ( struct list *tmp = head; tmp; tmp = tmp->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", tmp->value );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}    

void swap( struct list **head, int value )
{
    while ( *head && ( *head )->value != value )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    if ( *head && ( *head )->next )
    {
        struct list *next = ( *head )->next->next;
        ( *head )->next->next = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        ( *head )->next->next = next;
    }        
}

int main( void ) 
{
    struct list *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 2, -1, 7, 3, -5, 4 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
    {
        push_front( &head, a[i] );
        display( head );
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
        {            
            swap( &head, a[i] );
            display( head );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 

-1 2 
2 -1 

7 2 -1 
2 7 -1 
2 -1 7 

3 2 -1 7 
2 3 -1 7 
2 -1 3 7 
2 -1 7 3 

-5 2 -1 7 3 
2 -5 -1 7 3 
2 -1 -5 7 3 
2 -1 7 -5 3 
2 -1 7 3 -5 

4 2 -1 7 3 -5 
2 4 -1 7 3 -5 
2 -1 4 7 3 -5 
2 -1 7 4 3 -5 
2 -1 7 3 4 -5 
2 -1 7 3 -5 4 

2 -1 7 3 -5 4
```

As usual my answer is the best.:)